# Join numbers together in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm a beginner to R. What I want to do is join numbers together. I made a `data` as follows:

```
data<-data.frame(year=c(2020,2021,2022),month=c(10,11,12))
```

My expected output is as follows:

```
data=data.frame(year=c(2020,2021,2022),month=c(10,11,12),year_month=c(202010,202111,202212))
```

`year_month` is the column joining `year` and `month` together.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could concatenate the columns using `paste0` like this:

```r
data<-data.frame(year=c(2020,2021,2022),month=c(10,11,12))
data$year_month <- do.call(paste0, data)
data
#>   year month year_month
#> 1 2020    10     202010
#> 2 2021    11     202111
#> 3 2022    12     202212
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>